# Why does mpich not install correctly

Tags: apt, mpi

I'm on 16.04. When I

> sudo apt-get install mpich

and check the lib directory

> /usr/lib/mpich

it contains the include dir as expected, but the lib directory within it:

> /usr/lib/mpich/lib

is a symbolic link to:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

So as far as I can tell, there are no lib files and I can't compile code because it doesn't find the mpich libraries.

> /usr/lib/mpich$ readlink -f lib

Returns:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Here are the compilation and link commands:

> ifort -warn none  -O2    -I/usr/include/mpich/ -c boundary.F90 -o boundary.o
>
> ifort -o boundary.o -lmpi

and the error is:

> boundary.F90:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `mpi_sendrecv_'

and the link directory is

> /usr/include/mpich/lib

Comment: Based on the error message, the issue is **not** that `mpich` is not installed correctly, but that you are failing to link the necessary library for the function in question (which appears to be `libmpichfort` i.e. you need to add `-lmpichfort` to your link command)

Comment: That fixed it, if you want to add that as an answer I'll mark as correct. Strange though, as I've been using -lmpi for years on 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mpich` package only contains the program binaries necessary to run MPICH programs.

You will need to install the `libmpich-dev` package which includes the MPICH headers and static libraries, as well as the compiler wrappers needed to build MPICH programs.

---

Based on the error message you provided, the issue is not that `mpich` is not installed correctly, but that you are failing to link the necessary library for the function in question, which appears to be `libmpichfort`

i.e. you need to add

```
-lmpichfort
```

to your link command.

Comment: I already have libmpich-dev installed